# Google Places API - no results for known location

Tags: google-places-api

I am doing a google place search on a neighborhood in my area but when when I set the "type" to "neighborhood" I get zero results.  Is there a way to determine which type a location is?

Here is the query (well the entire url) I am using:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?key={myKEY}&location=38.9047,-77.0164&radius=99999&sensor=false&type=neighborhood&keyword=ballston+arlington,+va
```

So the lat/lng is set to DC with a large enough radius that Balltson should be well within its search.

Answer (score 0):

The `neighborhood` type is not supported in the `&type` parameter of a Place Search.  The [documentation says](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types#table2):

> The types below are **not supported** in the type filter of a place search, or in the types property when adding a place.

And `neighborhood` is in that list.

Perhaps the [Google Maps Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is a better fit?  E.g. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ballston+arlington,+va&key=<KEY>`